# what's the meaning of the below regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
data.replace(/(.*)/g, '$1')
```

I encountered the above in smashing nodejs, can someone quickly explain this syntax? I'm new to Regex.

Comment: Seems to be a _no-op_.

Comment: ...but quite a resource-intensive one...

Comment: @TimPietzcker Could you please explain why so?

Comment: @thefourtheye: It depends on what `data` contains, but if it contains a string with several newlines, that regex will match each line (except the newlines) and replace them with themselves. That takes some time and memory.

Comment: Visit this url for more information:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` means match characters except new line.

`*` matches 0 or more of the preceeding token. This is a greedy match, and will match as many characters as possible before satisfying the next token.

`$1` refers to the matched group.

`g` modifier means global, which in turn means,

> "don't stop at the first match. Continue to match even after that"

Basically what it is doing is capturing every character into a group until it encounters a `\n`(newline) and replacing it with the same.

There is no change in this operation and you should avoid doing this.

Comment: "Everything" is not entirely correct. The dot doesn't match newlines.

Comment: I think you can find more matches after new line. That pattern use 'g' (global match), isn't it??

Answer (score 1):

`.` can be any character, except the newline character, and `*` quantifier means that `.` can be matched 0 to unlimited times. So, it matches all the characters in the data. The parenthesis around `.*`, group all the matched characters into a group and `$1` refers to the first captured group. So, we basically match all the characters and replace that with the matched characters.

It is similar to doing

```
str.replace(str1, str1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You found it in "Smashing Node.js". I tried and found it too. There is the code: `data.replace(/(.*)/g, '  $1')` there. Please notice the two leading spaces before $1. It makes the indentation of the whole text.

1. `.*` matches the whole line,
2. replaces it with `" "` + the same line,
3. repeats it until eof because `g` modifier is there